# Edit Razor views in separate project without rebuild

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a setup where my Razor views are in one project (say, Project X) and have two other projects that use those views (an admin website and a user portal website). The problem with this setup is that editing a Razor view in Project X requires stopping and starting the debug session to see the changes on the websites.
Is there a problem with my setup, or is there some way I can edit the Razor views without having to do a full recompile?
(Note that editing a Razor view located directly in either of the web projects shows updates without having to restart)

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but you can run multiple projects at startup. I do it with MVC and WebApi projects in the same solution. So you can test against the WebApi from the MVC project.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your problem but I use the attach to process when I'm debugging and have a gulp task setup to copy view changes to my sandbox/localsite whenever I save a view

Comment: @SSharp yep, I'm already using multiple startup projects. It doesn't resolve my issue though.

Comment: @JKerny I guess something like that would work.  I was hoping there would be some checkbox option in Visual Studio that would magically make it work though :)